# What happened to replica's updated data after network partition restored

Tags: database, cap

I wonder is there is a recommendation policies or rules on how storages that implement AP with eventual consistency in CAP theorem should behave when network partition occurs and restores. AP means DBMS allows clients to do writes while replica node is disconnected from master. However when the network is back up and running, what happens to replica server's data that got written during the network disruption between the replica and leader/master?

As an example:

1. `Person` address happened to be updated in both leader and disconnected from the leader replica by conflicting data. Will replica's data to be replaced?
2. how about newly added records/documents to the replica? Will they be gone or synchronized back to the leader when connection is restored?

Comment: You tagged this question mysql. Are you asking specifically how MySQL solves this problem? The wording of your question seems to be asking more generally.

Comment: I targeted MySql as something that I'm very likely to be dealing with, but interested in more generic answer, so I've removed the tag. 

If answer depends on DBMS, I would be interested to hear how MySql handles the situation first of all. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of MySQL, data change events are written to a log on the source instance. The replica subscribes to this log remotely, so it downloads new events very promptly after they are committed to the log. Once it downloads that portion of the log, it can replay the events against its own instance of the data.

As long as the source instance doesn't purge the logs too quickly, the network can be interrupted, or the replica can be rebooted or whatever, and it will just pick up where it left off when it reconnects. Of course the replica must keep track of its progress in both downloading and replaying those events.

I have been supporting replica database instances that were offline for too long. For example if a piece of hardware in the replica's server needs to be replaced and it takes a few days to get it shipped, then the logs on the source are long gone by the time the replica finally tries to download them.

The replica has integrity only if it replays all the events, in the correct order. If it can't do that because the logs have expired, then the replica cannot recover. In that case, we reinitialize the replica by dropping all its data, get a new snapshot of the whole dataset from the source, and start again from that point. We had to do this several times a week, because we were running thousands of replicas.

---

Re your comments:

> Do you do reinitializing the replica manually or the entire process (drop data, restoring snapshot etc) could be done automatically?

It's difficult to make one solution that will work in everyone's environment.

At my last job, we developed our own automation to do this, so we could run one command to launch a background request to rebuild. It's the same steps that one would do manually, but we implemented them in code that would run in an automation service. That way we don't forget a step, we don't rely on anyone's laptop or interactive session, the automation has good quality assurance, it can do retries, can run multiple jobs in parallel, can report progress. But the solution was designed very custom for the environment we worked in. We had to comply with server naming conventions, network security policies, monitoring and alerting systems, etc.

[MySQL Clone plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/clone-plugin.html) is a recent new technology that claims to do a similar thing, but I haven't had an opportunity to try it.

> MySql does not allow to write to replica in any configuration, does it?

By default, MySQL does allow changes directly on a replica. Of course this can compromise integrity of the replica if you aren't careful. So in many environments, it's a good practice to set configuration options `read_only=ON` and `super_read_only=ON` on the replica to prevent it.

---

> what does happen to the replica's data, updated and inserted while disconnected from the source, when connection is restored and replica is able to sync up to the source? I wonder if all the writes to replica are going to be lost

MySQL replication doesn't do a full re-sync. It doesn't have any way of assuring that the replica is in sync with its source. Replication only replays incremental change events. This works if the two instances started from the same state, and all the changes are deterministic, so then they *should* stay in sync, in theory.

In practice, there's a nonzero risk of "data drift" — i.e. the replica's data diverges from the data on its source. MySQL's replication solution cannot detect data drift. There are third-party tools like [pt-table-checksum](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-table-checksum.html) that try to do this, but they aren't 100% perfect at detecting differences.

To minimize the risk:

- Never write changes directly to a replica while it is replicating.
- If a network partition occurs, rely on quorum. You would need an odd number of instances, so if there is a network partition, one or the other partition has the majority of instances, and can determine an instance to be the source. The instance(s) in the partition that does not have quorum must remain read-only.
- Use ROW-based replication instead of STATEMENT-based replication. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html

Comment: thanks for the detailed in comprehensible explanation. Do you do reinitializing the replica manually or the entire process (drop data, restoring snapshot etc) could be done automatically? Another question: MySql does not allow to write to replica in any configuration, does it?

Comment: thanks for addressing my questions, Bill. Since you said 'yes' on writing to replica, and it even happened to be mySql default configuration, one follow up question which was actually my original question: what does happen to the replica's data, updated and inserted while disconnected from the source, when connection is restored and replica is able to sync up to the source? I wonder if all the writes to replica are going to be lost